# Parse SDK JavaScript with Node.js ENOTFOUND

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, parse-platform

So I want to fetch a large amount of data on Parse, a good solution I found is to make a recursive function: when the data are successfully found, launch another request. The way I'm doing it is pretty simple:

```
var containedLimit = 1000, // Also tried with 500, 300, and 100
    parseUsersWaiting = {
        // A lot of Users
    },
    parseUsers = {}, // Recipt for Users
    getPlayers = function (containedIn) {        
        var count = 0;

        if (containedIn == undefined) {
            containedIn = [];

            for (var i in parseUsersWaiting) {
                count++;
                if (count > containedLimit) {
                    break;
                }

                containedIn.push(parseUsersWaiting[i].id);
                delete parseUsersWaiting[i];
            }
        }

        var UserObject = Parse.Object.extend('User'),
            UserQuery = new Parse.Query(UserObject);

        UserQuery.limit(containedLimit);

        UserQuery.containedIn('objectId', containedIn);
        UserQuery.find({
            success: function (results) {
                if (results) {
                    for (var i in results) {
                        if (parseUsers[results[i].id] == undefined) {
                            parseUsers[results[i].id] = results[i];
                        }

                        // Other stuff

                        if (results.length < containedLimit) {
                            // End of process
                        } else {
                            getPlayers();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Looks like an end of process too
                }
            }, error: function (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
                getPlayers(containedIn);
            }
        });
    };
```

Now, here is what I would like to call the "issue": it happen, very frequently, that the "error" callback is launched with this:

```
Received an error with invalid JSON from Parse: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.parse.com
at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
```

(With code 107, of course) So I searched on the Parse Documentation, and it says the exact same thing: "Received an error with invalid JSON". Yeah.

I'm using the Parse SDK provided by Parse.com (`npm install parse`)

I also tried to modify a bit the Parse code with replacing the `host` key by 'hostname' on line 361 of the file `parse/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js` (Parse package version: 1.5.0), and it didn't worked, so I removed my changes.

(By the way, I found a solution talking about using `ulimit` to change memory usage limit that could solve the problem, but actually, I haven't the necessary rights to execute this command)

Comment: What was the ulimit solution?

Comment: I found it [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/received-an-error-with-invalid-json-from-parse-error-connect-emfile), but actually it's not the same error

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs when it can not connect to the API (technically when it cannot lookup the IP address of the API server). Perhaps your internet connection was lost for a brief moment or their SDK server were unavailable (or maybe the server is denying your request due to rate limits).

Either way it is good to code some resilience into your application. I see your on error function retries the API call, but perhaps it would be worth adding a timeout before you do that to give the problem a chance to recover?

```
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        setTimeout(getPlayers, 10000, containedIn);
    }
```

If the sever is rate limiting your requests, this will also help.

Comment: The Parse server has a high rate limit (something like 100/s), also, I'm executing my script on an OVH server (so it should not go offline, plus, I'm connecting through SSH and I'm seeing the errors, so the server is, actually, not going offline) this error is happening a lot of time (It can happen something like each 15 requests).

Comment: Did the timeout help?

Comment: Can you add `Parse.prototype._api_host = '54.84.64.193'` to make sure it is not a dns issue? I think that will work, or you could add it to your /etc/hosts

Comment: After searching into the `parse/build/parse-latest.js`, there are no declaration for this var. Anyway, I tried your solution before a Parse.initialize(), it didn't worked (`Cannot set property '_api_host' of undefined`), so I tried directly with `Parse._api_host = '54.84.64.193'` and it didn't worked neither, also, of course, the timeout could work, but I’m trying to avoid this error completely

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and add a line at the end saying `api.parse.com 54.84.64.193` just to rule out the dns as an issue